# Django error: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

It's taking me way to long to make this simple form.  Almost there but when I submit I get the NoneType error

views.py:

```
from djangoproject1.authentication import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def main(request):
    rf = forms.RegisterForm()
    pf = forms.ProfileForm()
    return render_to_response("authentication/index.html", {'form1': rf, 'form2':pf})

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        rf = forms.RegisterForm(request.POST)
        pf = forms.ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if rf.is_valid() and pf.is_valid():
            newuser = User(username=rf.cleaned_data['username'],email=rf.cleaned_data['email']) # this is the offending line
            newuser.set_password(rf.cleaned_data['password'])
            newuser.save()
            profile = pf.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = newuser
            profile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/register-success/")
    else: 
        return main(request)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from djangoproject1.authentication.models import UserProfile    

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(min_length=6,max_length=15)
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6,max_length=15,widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    cpassword = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password',widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail Address')

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phonenumber = forms.CharField(label='Phone Number')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user')
```

Stack trace:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/register/
Django Version: 1.2.1
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'djangoproject1.authentication']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\jec23\My Java Projects\djangoproject1\src\djangoproject1\..\djangoproject1\authentication\views.py" in register
  21.             newuser = User(username=rf.cleaned_data['username'],email=rf.cleaned_data['email'])

Exception Type: TypeError at /register/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the error?

Comment: stack trace posted.  It wasn't very helpful except for displaying where the error was coming from.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `clean` method in the forms.py should return the `self.cleaned_data`, if it doesn't raise an error.

Currently, it is returning None (as you are not returning anything explicitly)

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I didn't realize I had to return cleaned_data.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the contents of this line:

```
newuser = User(username=rf.cleaned_data['username'],email=rf.cleaned_data['email'])
```

it seems to me that the form instance `rf` doesn't have a `cleaned_data` field. The `'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable` error can be raised when you are trying to access `cleaned_data` like you would access a dictionary but `cleaned_data` is actually `None`.

To check (rather clumsily) add a `print` statement before the offending line:

```
print rf.cleaned_data
```

OK. On closer look this is the most likely culprit:

```
def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
```

`Clean` methods should return `cleaned_data` explicitly. Since this one is not, it causes an  error.